I can't run this assembly code on my Windows
I want to do the typical Hello World in assembler from my Windows with 64-byte architecture, and it simply doesn't show me anything when running the executable program.
extern printf                           

section .data
    msg db "Hello, World", 10, 0                             

section .text
    global main                        

main:
    push rbp

    mov rdi, msg                                     
    mov rax, 0
    call printf

    pop rbp

    mov rax, 0            
    ret

To assemble NASM occupies:
nasm -f win64 .\hello_world.asm -o .\hello_world.obj
And to link the object file I finally use the gcc compiler:
gcc hello_world.obj -o hello_world.exe -lkernel32 -lmsvcrt
Finally, when running the executable nothing happens, here I show you what the prompt looks like:
PS C:\Users\rober\Documents\Personal\ASM\x86_64-win-64> .\hello_world.exe

PS C:\Users\rober\Documents\Personal\ASM\x86_64-win-64> 

It literally doesn't display anything, I don't know if there's something wrong with the code (but when assembling it should give me an error, which doesn't happen). It doesn't give an error when assembling or when linking, I don't know if there's an error that goes unnoticed or if it's an issue with my machine...

Windows calling convention passes the first 4 integer class arguments in RCX, RDX, R8, and R9. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170 . RDI (and setting AL to 0) suggests to me you may have got confused with the Linux 64-bit convention.

this question is worth up-voting because it is formulated properly. It even shows the exact command that was typed and the empty prompt. (Because I was about to ask "exactly how do you know your program prints nothing?")

You also need to reserve shadow space (sub rsp, 32, or sub rsp, 40 if you don't waste an instruction pushing RBP) before calling another function, otherwise it will trash your return address.  See Hello World using NASM (and GoLink) on x64 64 bit Windows for a working example using WriteFile instead of printf.
